# Drupal views glossary for non latin letters

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-views

Well, I have searched on drupal.org and stack overflow and couldn't find a similar problem, I hope i didn't miss something.

I'm building a site in drupal 7 where I have content that needs to be **grouped by letters**. The views build in glossary seems the best solution and it works well. The only problem is that I use non Latin letters like Č Đ Č Š Ž and the **order is messed up**. I need the order to be like in **Gaj's Latin alphabet**:

A B C Č Ć D Dž Đ E F G H I J K L Lj M N Nj O P R S Š T U V Z Ž

as you can see there is also a problem because there are letters with "two letters", but displaying Lj as L would be a solution I could live with. The biggest problem is that C and Ć  is displayed under Č but Đ is separated from D, so i get:

A (1) | Č (3) | D (1) | Ž (1) | Đ (1) for example.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem? To seperate the C and Ć from Č or to merge D and Đ. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite late to the party on this one,

**The bad news** : This is entirely due to SQL collation and not Views. The usual database collation for Drupal, *utf8_general_ci* instructs MySQL to treat those characters as equal in GROUP and WHERE statements.

In particular; the views query to generate a glossary is currently:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1) AS title_truncated, COUNT(node.nid)
AS num_records
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('my_nodetype')) ))
GROUP BY title_truncated
ORDER BY title_truncated ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The GROUP BY here obliterates any difference between collation-listed-as-equal unicode characters, because it groups and treats them as equal.

**The good news** : this is quickly solved by implementing hook_views_query_alter() to instruct MySQL to GROUP and WHERE to use the collation *utf8_bin* for your view.

```php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    // Stop the glossary from treating characters equal.
    if ($view->is_attachment) {
      foreach ($query->groupby as &$condition_group) {
        if ($condition_group == 'title_truncated') {
          $condition_group = "title_truncated COLLATE utf8_bin";
        }
      }
    }
    // Rewrite the attached view to filter on unique characters.
    else {
      foreach ($query->where as &$condition_where) {
        foreach ($condition_where['conditions'] as &$cur_condition) {
          if ($cur_condition['field'] == 'SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1) = :node_title') {
            $cur_condition['field'] = 'SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1) = :node_title COLLATE utf8_bin';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful to anyone else encountering this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site all in Russian? If so, please check this page, [Install Drupal 7.0 in your language out of the box!](http://localize.drupal.org/node/2609) It is found at localize.Drupal.org the localization subdomain of drupal.org, which is dedicated to creating Drupal sites in languages other than English. With Drupal 7, it is possible to install a localized version in many languages, including Russian.

While I haven't tried it, I believe it would be worthwhile to install a localized version to see if the glossary works as you would like. If not, let us know back here.

Comment: The site is in Serbian and the translation isn't finished yet at Drupal. But still I think that even with the translation the letters order will remain the same. I managed to find a solution with taxonomy. I crated a vocabulary with all the letters I needed and used weight to order them. Even the Lj, Nj... are no problem. Then in views I created a block and now i can put the letters wherever I want :)

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the issue. Taxonomy and Views can do so much together!